# how can i make image span clickable in Android?

Tags: android, bitmap, expandablelistview, spannable, clickable-image

I have an ExpandableListView and in the ViewGroup method i have an image span set to some textview like this:

```
String statusText = postsList.get(groupPosition).get(TAG_userStatus).substring(urlStr.length(), postsList.get(groupPosition).get(TAG_userStatus).length()); 
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(urlStr);//urlStr is the path to my image: /mnt/sdcard/1.jpg
Bitmap resized = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bm, 200, 200, true);                                 
TextView userStatus1 = (TextView)v.findViewById( R.id.userStatus );
SpannableStringBuilder ssb = new SpannableStringBuilder(" "+statusText );
ImageSpan span = new ImageSpan(resized, ImageSpan.ALIGN_BOTTOM);    

ssb.setSpan( span, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE );  
userStatus1.setText( ssb, BufferType.SPANNABLE );
```

I need to be able to click on the image and show it in full screen.But I don't know how to make the image clickable. I have read similar threads but nothing works for me. I think it's because expandableListView but I'm not sure. I hope you can help me. Thank you!

Comment: are you sure you cannot get the click event from "userStatus1" textView?

Comment: but i need it from the image within textview...

Comment: but have you tried it? since the image is now part of the textview i think should do the trick...

Comment: it was part of the textview. But now i put them in separately views(i replaced spannablestringbuilder with an imageview) and it works. Thank you anyway!